# Halogen torchiere standing lamp

Tags: lighting

Do they make halogen torchiere-type standing lamps anymore? I can't seem to find them anywhere, while 5-10 years ago they were quite common. The amount of light they throw off was so superior even to big incandescent lamps, not to mention wimpy CFLs. And they had a nice dimmer type operation.

Comment: They are really hot, making them a fire hazard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think they stopped making them because they kept catching on fire.

Google search: ["Halogen Lamp Fire Hazard"](http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=halogen+lamp+fire+hazard)

Comment: Hmmm. I saw this article from the NYTimes from 1997. But it looks like most of the problems came from dumb college students who draped clothes on top of a really hot lamp. Too bad; I love the color of halogen light. http://www.nytimes.com/1997/01/16/garden/fire-hazards-seen-in-some-torchere-style-halogen-lamps.html

Comment: @bshor - I agree, they were great lights.  I guess this is a case where public perception won out over common sense and fact?

Answer (score 1):

I am still looking for one.  It provided the best color lighting for my office and home.

Certainly they must still be available somewhere.

Comment: LED lights are now a good replacement. Good quality light and energy efficient, too.